# git fetch --dry-run still changes the local repo and transfer data

Tags: git

I'm trying to test if a remote repo has a given SHA.  ls-remote does not work for this unless it is a tag or a HEAD (which is not guaranteed for this case).

`git fetch --dry-run $remote $rev` SEEMS to fit the bill, except it changes local state.  For example:

```
$ git cat-file -t f80f1b23b4cab2a295a091c623bb4746d188bd4a
fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info

$ git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD
42d21cf12aab73ac8bc6245cc74ac9850bdf6989

$ git fetch --dry-run file:///tmp/e2e.2527526915/repo f80f1b23b4cab2a295a091c623bb4746d188bd4a
remote: Enumerating objects: 20, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (18/18), 415.91 KiB | 84.00 KiB/s, done.
From file:///tmp/e2e.2527526915/repo
 * branch            f80f1b23b4cab2a295a091c623bb4746d188bd4a -> FETCH_HEAD

$ git cat-file -t f80f1b23b4cab2a295a091c623bb4746d188bd4a
commit

$ git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD
42d21cf12aab73ac8bc6245cc74ac9850bdf6989
```

FETCH_HEAD was not updated (good) but the rev is question is now present locally (bad), further tested by making a very large commit and watching the fetch be very slow.

Am I using `--dry-run` wrong?  Is there a different way to ask for what I want?

Comment: I probs am mistaken, but wouldn't the `--no-write-fetch-head` in addition to the `--dry-run` be of use in this case? Reading the doc is suggesting something like that.

Comment: `--no-write-fetch-head` says "Under --dry-run option, the file is never written"

Comment: After some tests, I think `--dry-run` is bypassed if the remote repository lies on the same machine (or can be accessed to via a local path) no matter which protocol the URL uses. I also tried `git://` and `ssh://`.

Comment: @ElpieKay: that seems like a bug (probably reported long ago and still unfixed for some internal hard-to-fix-it reason or something)...

Comment: Same behavior on a github repo

Comment: @torek I made more tests with some old versions (among which the oldest is 2.15.1) and repositories hosted in our Gerrit and Gitlab. With `--dry-run` it also fetches data which does not exist in the local repository yet. Now I feel confused and my knowledge about `--dry-run` is challenged.

Comment: It seems that --dry-run prevent FETCH_HEAD from being updated and not much else